# Json.net start from value in array

Tags: json, vb.net, linq, json.net

Hey all i have the following json response that i am trying to find:

```
{
"threaded_extended": {
"3570956071": [
  {
    "id": [edited],
    "network_id": [edited],
    "sender_type": "user",
    "url": "[edited]",
    "sender_id": [edited],
    "privacy": "public",
    "body": {
      "rich": "[edited]",
      "parsed": "[edited]",
      "plain": "[edited]"
    },
    "liked_by": {
      "count": 0,
      "names": []
    },
    "thread_id": [edited],
```

I am trying to find **3570956071** but i cant seem to find it using JSON.net.

My code is this:

```
    Dim url As String = "https://www.[edited].json?access_token=" & yAPI.userToken & "&threaded=extended"
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd)

For Each msg3 As JObject In o("threaded_extended")("3570956071")
'etc etc....
```

And i get the error: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

I have even tried:

```
For Each msg3 As JObject In o("threaded_extended")
'etc etc....
```

And get the error: **Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.**

And finally just doing this:

```
For Each msg3 As JObject In o("3570956071")
'etc etc....
```

gives me the error: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

What am i missing?

**UPDATE**

The value of o("3570956071") is **Nothing**.

But as you see in the json resonse, its there..

Doing o("threaded_extended") gives me the number within the debug.

The debug looks like this:

```
"3570956071": [
{
  "chat_client_sequence": null,
  "replied_to_id": [edited],
  "network_id": [edited],
  "created_at": "2013/08/27 19:26:41 +0000",
  "privacy": "public",
  "attachments": [],
  "sender_id": [edited],
  "liked_by": {
    "names": [],
    "count": 0
  },
  "system_message": false,
  "group_id": [edited],
  "thread_id": [edited],
  'etc etc
```

But continuing from that it shows that error **Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'**

Comment: doesnt this line need a NEW statement? `Dim o As NEW JObject = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd)`

Comment: @Mertis all my other stuff that gathers from the json return works but this one so i know its not due to that.

Comment: step through the code. At which specific line is the error occurring at?

Comment: @Mertis any **For Each msg3 As JObject In o(xxxxxxxxx)** combination that i've try above in my OP.

Comment: This leads me to believe that o is not instantiated, hence my stating you need to use the NEW keyword as i stated before.

Comment: @Mertis Again, its not that.

Comment: maybe its because you shouldnt be doing a for each msg3 to find what you are looking for.  Just try to get ahold of it doing `o("3570956071").tostring` set it equal to some string variable then check if it is empty.  If its empty, it wasnt found.

Comment: Updated my OP with debug info.

Comment: Which version of Json.Net are you using? I cannot reproduce this on v4.5.0.0

Comment: @ChiChan I'm using version 4.5 of JSON.net

Answer (score 0):

The exception `Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'` is because `JObject`'s default member, `Item(String)`, returns a JToken object, which is a superclass to JContainer, which is in turn a superclass to JProperty and JObject.  If you change your For Each loop to look like this

```
For Each msg3 As JToken In o("3570956071")
    If msg3.GetType() Is GetType(JObject) Then
        ..etc..
    ElseIf msg3.GetType() Is GetType(JProperty) Then
        ..etc..
    End If
Next
```

It should prevent in invalid cast from happening.

Comment: That did not work. It didnt even know what to do with the JObject/JProperty varible.

Comment: And doing this **For Each msg3 As JToken In o("threaded_extended")** was the only way to have it not error on that line but it still does not pass the JObject/JProperty varible.

Comment: The error is **JObject' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.**

Comment: My apologies... brain compiler and iphone typing lead me to the wrong type of `Type` evaluation.  I'm updating the sample now.